# use_page_number show wrong data in page

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I'm really need your help about pagination.

Already tried to search and not found the answer.

So my problem is my pagination page not show a correct data when I used use_page_number into true.
When I set it to false, my pagination show correct data but the link url not show current page.

> With use_page_number is TRUE
>
> **Example 1 : per_page is 2;**
>
> Page 1 : 1,2
>
> Page 2 : 3,4
>
> Page 3 : 4,5 -> repeated data
>
> **Example 2 : per_page is 1**
>
> Page 1 : 1
>
> Page 2 : 3 -> this should 2
>
> Page 3 : blank -> this should 3
>
> **Example 3 : per_page is 5**
>
> Page 1 : 1,2,3,4,5
>
> Page 2 : 3,4,5,6,7
>
> Page 3 : 4,5,6,7,8
>
> **With use_page_numbers is false**
>
> Page 'blank' : 1,2
>
> Page 2 : 3,4
>
> Page 4 : 5
>
> I know that CI pagination not show current page we are, but need
>   use_page_numbers (correct me if I'm wrong), but not work in my code :(

I really dont know what's wrong, could you please guys help me to solve it?
This is my code :

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url()."admin/user/index/";
            $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('msuser');
            $config['per_page'] = 3;
            $config['num_links'] = 2;
            $config['first_link'] = 'First';
            $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
            $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
            $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
            $config['full_tag_close'] ="</ul>";
            $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
            $config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
            $config['next_link'] = '&raquo;';
            $config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
            $config['next_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
            $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo;';
            $config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
            $config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
            $config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
            $config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
            $config['last_tag_open'] = "<li>";
            $config['last_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
            $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            $data['user'] = $this->user_model->getUserByPage($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(4));
            $data['main'] = 'admin/user_view';
            $this->load->view('admin/dashboard',$data);
```

really appreciate for your help guys.

thanks

Comment: what is the name of your controller? admin or user ?

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply.
my controller name is index.

hmm, I think the problem is in the offset.

after I change the offset this works perfectly :)

($this->uri->segment(4,1)-1)*$config['per_page'])

Comment: When you use page numbers, you'll have to calculate the offset yourself. Otherwise you'll end up with the wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try change a few your code:

```
$page_num = $this->uri->segment(4);

($page_num>1)? $start = ($page_num - 1) * $config['per_page'] : $start = $page_num;

$data['user'] = $this->user_model->getUserByPage($config['per_page'], $start);
```